# Bluetooth always restarts if I try to connect any device

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and everytime I try to connect any device, the bluetooth will turn off, then on without letting the device connect at all. My computer has windows 10 installed, and it has no problem connecting, what leads me to believe that its not hardware

I tried reinstalling bluez, restarting the service, removing all devices then reinstalling bluez. Nothing worked.